# What colors of the sky can humans breathe?

Tags: science-based, atmosphere, terraforming

*Apologies for the extremely weird title. Admittedly, it describes my question well.*

Now, I'm making a universe where humans have discovered the big secret to space travel. It's actually pretty simple; all you have to do is ████████. Who'd have thought?

Now, the problem with easy space travel in a species with low lifespan is that terraforming takes too long. Humans don't wanna wait for stuff, so instead of letting our machines make the planet perfect, we have a tendency to settle when it's barely livable. That means that not all of the chemicals and stuff are out of the air, but there's nothing so toxic that it'd kill people very fast.

With that in mind, what colors can the sky be if the atmosphere is breathable?

For the sake of the question, please also assume that the gravity, temperature, etc. of the planet is also livable, with modern-day tech. High-altitude stuff is fine -- as long as people can live on the surface, I don't care. Space ships are airtight anyway.

<sup>Bonus points if you make it snow- or cold-related.</sup>

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. The sky is blue because [Rayleigh scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering) affects blue light more than red. If you have very thin atmosphere, the color will tend towards black, and if you have very thick atmosphere, the color will tend towards white. A thin atmosphere where the light travels a long way (such as during sunrise/sunset) causes the scattered blue light to scatter all the way to the ground/space before it gets to us, making it red. Any other colors are from chemicals in the atmosphere, which can probably be any color.

Comment: @MichaelS "Any other colors are from chemicals in the atmosphere, which can probably be any color." What I'm asking is what chemicals can I put in the air to turn the sky different colors without killing people. I'd imagine that, while you could make an atmosphere any color by putting the right stuff in, not all of it is breathable. If that made sense, feel free to edit the question to clarify; I just realized how tired I am.

Comment: But it's basically asking for a negative answer. "Prove that no safely-breathable chemicals in the galaxy can produce a yellow atmosphere", etc. But a further complication is that high-altitude chemicals could cause the weird colors without affecting the humans on the ground, depending on the atmosphere of this random planet. So it's not even about safe chemicals, just chemicals that might possibly exist safely.

Comment: @MichaelS ...Quit being pedantic, please. It's implied that I mean "of the chemicals that can form naturally and that we know about", so no, it's not any possible chemical. Second, high-altitude things are fine. As I said in my question, I'm looking for what I can get away with without killing people. Third, does any other question here that asks "what can be done" require that any idea not suggested be proven impossible? No. They don't. Because that's not the question. Again, if you feel like you can clarify that, please do.

Comment: I feel like this is a little too broad. There are thousands (if not millions) of possible chemicals that could be in the atmosphere, and their effect on light may not be known to us. This would produce list-based answers or incomplete answers as best. If you want a particular atmospheric color for a planet, appropriate amounts of handwavium always make it the right color.

Comment: @DonyorM I'm not certain that's true, but whatever. It's late and I'll edit tomorrow to make it clearer what I'm asking, since apparently English isn't my strong suit when I should have been asleep hours ago.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Cool, if you improve it I'm more than happy to remove the close vote.

Comment: You might fare a little bit better if you look for specific colors that can be breathable. For example, I want the atmosphere here to be yellow, is that possible? While I approve of the idea of the question, it does seem a little bit broad. Although you earned an upvote from me. How do you do the blackout thing, by the way?

Comment: @XandarTheZenon: It's a specific character, █, I believe Unicode 2588. You can copy/paste it. There are also ▀ ▄ ▌ ▐ characters (top half, bottom half, left half, right half), along with dithers, ▓▒░, card suits, ♥♣♦♠, arrows, ▲►▼◄, smilies, ☺☻, musical symbols, ♪♫♯, and even a sun, ☼, in that part of the unicode characters.

Comment: I've given an answer to your question illustrating the wide array of colors already known to be possible. My concern with the question isn't proving a specific color is possible. My concern is that basically any color is possible, so the only sensible answers to the question besides "whatever color you want" involve very careful analysis of every possible known chemical that could naturally exist in an oxygen-rich environment in every known atmospheric type to demonstrate that certain colors *aren't* possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment that may or may not get deleted, I think the question itself is *very* broad. There's just no way to reasonably prove that some particular color isn't possible. That said, we can show that most colors are possible, as long as you don't need it to be some really specific shade.

**TL;DR**

[Red from dust](http://www.quick-tech-news.com/tag/red-sky), [yellow from dust](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3226577/Sandstorm-engulfs-Middle-East-killing-eight-people-causing-hundreds-hospitalised-respiratory-problems.html), [green from storms](https://www.flickr.com/photos/sklee/5779077169), and [blue from Rayleigh scattering](http://www.photovaco.com/photos/background/blue-sky-912/) are all perfectly normal here on Earth under conditions that could conceivably be permanent on another planet. Purple is probably possible with a slightly hotter sun and some atmospheric dust that absorbs yellow and green light.

**Light Source**

The reason our sky is blue is because of [Rayleigh scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering), which preferentially scatters shorter-wavelength (higher frequency, higher energy, blue-er) light. That will be true of any atmosphere, regardless of composition, but only for the colors that actually survive the trip.

The first part of having colors survive the trip, is they need to exist at the beginning. A star's temperature determines what colors it outputs. See [black body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_body) radiation topics for more information. A "cold" star (around 3000 K or 5000 °F) will be red. Meaning your sky (and everything else you look at) will be red. As the star gets hotter, the color will progress through orange and yellow, then start becoming whiter and whiter, but the sky will always tend towards the shortest wavelengths visible, so it could look red, yellow, green, or blue. If you make the sun hotter than ours, you could conceivably get a purplish sky, although oxygen tends to absorb light in that part of the spectrum (and we can't see a huge range of purple colors -- most purple colors are the absence of green).

Note that for most of these sky colors, the planet won't be incredibly nice visually, because without artificial light sources, you'll get monochrome or duochrome everything. So if you want normal-ish world lighting with a different-colored sky, you have to rely on chemicals in the atmosphere.

**Chemical Filters**

There are two methods of changing the atmospheric color through chemicals. One is by changing the gases in the atmosphere itself (fluorine turns the atmosphere yellow, while chlorine turns it green). The other is by constantly kicking up a bunch of dust of a specific color (red dust will absorb the blue and green light, so only red light is able to refract down to observers on the ground).

Both of the gases listed seem to be toxic in the concentrations needed to change the sky color, so it might be safer using dust particles. Mars is a reddish-orange color because of the oxidized iron in its dust. So adding extra oxygen won't change the color much. Sand on Earth is generally a desaturated yellow color (also known as shades of brown), so anything in that range is clearly possible. Green skies can occur on Earth near thunderstorms (it seems particularly prevalent if there's hail but a quick Google search says we're not really sure what causes it), so a planet with a lot of upper-atmosphere storminess could give green (of note, this is thought to relate to ice in the atmosphere, which could be related to your very cold planet).

Again, the further you are from an Earth-like blue sky, the more of an effect you'll have on anything at the ground level. So bright, pure yellow skies will mean red and green stuff shows up decently, but blue objects will look black. But a faded yellow (which means there are other colors besides yellow, but yellow is the brightest) will be perceived as a yellow sky while still making ground objects relatively normal. Note that even our sky isn't really blue -- it's a faded (whitish) cyan/blue color. But you can still get a reasonably pure sky color without sacrificing ground visuals too much.

Of note, the denser the atmosphere, the more Rayleigh scattering has an effect (and the less relative effect the dust particles have). So for humans to live, we need something more dense than Mars, which means the atmosphere can't be as red, but it can still be fairly red to orange, especially with a mildly colder star. Purple skies can exist with any compound that mostly absorbs green, but I'm not sure what that would be. All the purple compounds I looked up react with oxygen to turn some other color.

Comment: So, because I ended up not having the chance to edit my question and I've since forgotten what I originally wanted to ask, I'm accepting this answer, because it's detailed and answers what I asked.